# Forbidden error for alias directories on Apache

Tags: apache, fedora, httpd.conf

Help needed regarding setting alias for my web server. I'm getting 403 Forbidden error.

I need to create alias for web directory, that is pladed in:

```
/var/falcon/
```

My file /etc/httpd/conf.d/helpdesk.conf looks like this:

```
Alias /hd/ "/var/falcon/"
<Directory "/var/falcon">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Directory /var/falcon is owned by apache user and by apache group.

SeLinux is enabled, so I run following directives:

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
chcon -R --reference=/var/www/html /var/falcon/
chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t
chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/falcon/
```

But, as I said, I'm getting 403 Forbidden error, if I open ie. https://my-domain.com/hd

Can you help me how can I use /var/falcon/ direcotry as a web direcotry.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution was very simple - all I was missing was "Require all granted" directive.

So, my conf file looks like this:

```
Alias /hd/ "/var/falcon/"
<Directory "/var/falcon">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I'm surprised it worked as `Order allow,deny` and `Allow from all` are for Apache 2.2 while `Require all granted` is for Apache 2.4 and should never be used together. You should be able to remove the first two and have it work just as well.